# Is this XAML <Style> a bad example?

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, itemscontrol

In a `<ControlTemplate>` for a `Control` that inherits from `ItemsControl`, I have defined the following:

```
<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.MinHeight" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="7,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Button.MinWidth" Value="75" />
            <Setter Property="Button.MaxWidth" Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="Button.Height" Value="23" />
        </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I keep wondering whether this is a good practice. Note that the control in question should only accept objects that descend from `FrameworkElement`. Note also that I want to avoid having to write a `ItemContainerStyleSelector` and would like to do that in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

I find it to be better practice to set the TargetType on the Style tag itself than qualifying each property with their actual type. Is your generic list adding multiple types of elements? If so you need to consider that all of these setters may not mesh well with different types of elements.

Comment: I have found that out. The list could take any descendant of `FrameworkElement`. I have made the control to template and style a Panel—as AFAIK there is no possibility to template `Grid`s.

Comment: @Minustar Correct, Grid would need to inherit Control to have a Template.  With little effort you could make a custom control that behaves like a grid but inherits from Control.